# Change domain of firebase dynamic link

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'ma trying to change the short dynamic link generated dynamically in code. For example "https://abc123.app.goo.gl/WXYZ" should be something like this "https://mywebsite.app.goo.gl/WXYZ".

If you guys can help me out I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Hello, did you had any luck with that ? I need to do the same thing

Comment: Hi Frank, nope.. I finished my internship before I could fix this issue. But it should be possible though to change the domain of the link.

Answer (score 1):

Please open Firebase support request for this. You will need to provide some proof that are the owner of the mywebsite.com.